# How can I replicate Pydantic v1 behaviour of json_encoders in pydantic v2?

Tags: python, pydantic

The latest versions of Pydantic v2 have resurrected the configuration option of `json_encoders` (see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.json_encoders)

However the following example, does not work as in v1.

v2:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    foo_bytes: bytes
    foo_params: list = Field(default_factory=list)
    model_config = ConfigDict(json_encoders={
        bytes: lambda x: f"0x{x.hex()}"
    })


foo_data = bytes(b"hello_world")
foo = Foo(foo_bytes=foo_data, foo_params=[foo_data],)

print(foo.model_dump_json())
# prints: '{"foo_bytes":"0x68656c6c6f5f776f726c64","foo_params":["hello_world"]}'
```

v1:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    foo_bytes: bytes
    foo_params: list = Field(default_factory=list)
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            bytes: lambda x: f"0x{x.hex()}",
        }


foo_data = bytes(b"hello_world")
foo = Foo(foo_bytes=foo_data, foo_params=[foo_data],)

print(foo.json())
# prints: '{"foo_bytes": "0x68656c6c6f5f776f726c64", "foo_params": ["0x68656c6c6f5f776f726c64"]}'
```

Any suggestions on how I can replicate the behaviour of v1 in v2?

Answer (score 0):

Once you declare the list as `list[bytes]` it works as expected:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class Foo(BaseModel):
    foo_bytes: bytes
    foo_params: list[bytes]
    model_config = ConfigDict(json_encoders={
        bytes: lambda x: f"0x{x.hex()}"
    })


foo_data = bytes(b"hello_world")
foo = Foo(foo_bytes=foo_data, foo_params=[foo_data],)

print(foo.model_dump_json())
```

Which prints:

```
{"foo_bytes":"0x68656c6c6f5f776f726c64","foo_params":["0x68656c6c6f5f776f726c64"]}
```

The way pydantic v2 works internally is that it build a json schema on model definition. So I'm not sure one can re-create the behavior of v1 where the type of the list items remains undefined. In case you have multiple valid items for the list you can always work with a `Union`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately `Union` does not seem to work with nested containers. e.g. something like that might work:    foo_params: list[Union[bytes,int,str]]` but not if the list may contain other dicts or lists. So this is something that used to work in V1 but not in V2 and hence the question remains: What is the proper way to replicate V1 behaviour in V2